# Get substring after specific pattern, split or look behind?

Tags: perl

How can I get the dates after `SP^` in:

```
89564;02/03/2005;;MT;M^08/17/75^F^12/28/2004^SP^07/22/57
89565;02/03/2005;DUO;MG;M^07/24/50^F^05/11/82^F^03/01/92^F^04/20/1986^SP^09/03/51
```

Not sure if I can use a lookbehind since I don't want the delimiter, only the dates. Can I split and get specifically the dates after `SP^`?

`SP^` is in different positions in the dataset, not always the last substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is enough for your examples:

```
print "$1\n" if $s =~ /SP\^(.*)$/;
```

but if you want to be specific about the date format:

```
print "$1\n" if $s =~ m!SP\^(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)!;
```

Comment: Liked the second one better! Thank you very much!

Comment: PBP: `$line =~ m{ \b SP \^ ( \d\d \/ \d\d \/ \d\d ) }msx`